# css: position child element on top of parents sibling

Tags: css

I have two elements next to eachother, both can scroll individually. The structure looks like this:

```
<splitter>
    <split-pane class="resizable">
        <article class="content">
            <div class="bar-foo">
            <div class="positionable"></div>
        </div>
        </article>
        <splitter-control class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></splitter-control>
    </split-pane>
    <split-pane >
        <article class="content">
            <div class="bar-foo foo-bar"></div>
        </article>
    </split-pane>
</splitter>
```

([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vfm5/667/))

In the first element I have this absolute positioned element. What I want is that this absolute positioned element also moves with the scrolling but is on top of everything else. The demo almost does this, except that it is not on top of the second `split-pane`.

I tried to change the overflow property from the `.content` class to

```
.content {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    ...
```

But doesn't do much :(

Can this be done ? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you please clarify what you want to happen? Are you saying that the first pane is working properly and you want a similarly positioned element in the second pane?

Comment: Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vfm5/671/). Visually this is what I want, the `positionable` element is on top of everything else, except it doesn't move when scrolling its parent. As soon as I add `position: relative;` to its parent (`.bar-foo`) it does scroll, but it is hidden behind its parent sibling

Comment: seems like this works http://jsfiddle.net/4Vfm5/670/

Comment: visually yes, but it doesn't scroll with its parent